# Pytest Selenium Headless mode moves downloaded file in the downloads folder after finishing all the remaining tests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

iam working on a pytest selenium chrome based web automation testing framework iam having a problem:
Goal Testcase will download the file by clicking an export button and then assert wheather the file was downloaded in the downloads folder or not

What is Working? It works fine in selenium headed mode chrome and firefox both

Problem: when iam running same testcase on the chrome headless mode it does not downloads the file and when all the tests execution completed the suddenly file appears in downloads folder which is causing my testcase as failed because its aim is to download the file and check if its in the downloads folder or not , why selenium in headless mode downloads the file after ending the session?
[GithubFrameworkRepoLink](https://github.com/HassanAbbas7357/WebAutomationTestingFramework)

i tried to do driver.quit() in the middle of my testcase but it didn’t worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.